# Персональный поиск яндекса просмотр результатов с другого ПК

Tags: windows, сеть, ubuntu, порты, поиск

Имеется 2 ПК: Windows XP и Ubuntu 12.04. На обоих системах установлен "Персональный поиск Яндекса". Задача: находясь под Ubuntu просматривать результаты поиска на ПК с ОС Windows. На обеих машинах локальный поиск работает так: http://127.0.0.1:9375/ . Пробую к адресу машины добавить порт 9375, но страничка не доступна. Вероятно, необходимо открыть порты на удалённой машине, но как это сделать я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант [Архивариус 3000](http://www.likasoft.com/ru/document-search/) Но он платный.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 9375 -j ACCEPT
```

Вроде так. Если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы напишите что это означает.

Comment: Эта команда открывает порт на ubuntu

Comment: Да ище надо будет и на windows порт открыть или файер выключить

Comment: а как определить в Windows 7 (в место ХР поставил) открыт ли порт? Прописал в ubuntu эту строку, в браузере захожу по адресу  http://127.0.0.1:9375/Пишет, что сервер отказал в подключении

Comment: отключение брендмауэра ни чего не дало. антивирус не установлен